# ko.utils.arrayFilter not working properly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to filter an array by omitting users that are already in a previous list:

> FullList: Tom, Tim, Jim, Jill
>   UsersList: Tom, Jill

and with the help of another member I was able to use this array filter but the problem is that the filter result is the same as the usersList: Tom, Jill and i want the filter result to be Tim, Jim

```
var viewModel = function(data){
    var _self = {};
    var FullUsers = ko.observableArray([]);
    var Users = ko.observableArray([]);

    _self.UsersList = function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, user) {
           _self.Users.push(new userViewModel(user));
        }
    }

    _self.FullList = function(data){
        $.each(data, function(index, user) {
           _self.FullUsers.push(new userViewModel(user));
        }
    }
    this._FilteredUsers=ko.computed(function() {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(_self.FullUsers(), function(item) {
        return ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(_self.Users(), item)<0;
      });
    });
}
```

I have two different get methods one for getting users and the other for full users - they are both the same the only difference is the id I pass in to one and the other doesn't require a passed id.

View Data-bind

```
<div data-bind="foreach: _FilteredUsers">
   <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
</div>
```

how can i alter the code so my result is Tim, Jim?

Current results based off above code - i get FullUsers including the once I don't want to show. when I flip the `Users()` and `FullUsers()` I am only getting Users list

Comment: Please post actual syntactically correct code! There is no `ArrayFilter` method it is called `arrayFilter` and also there is no `ArrayIndexOf` it is called `arrayIndexOf`!

Comment: @nemesv Sorry there!!! by regarding the syntactically correct code - since i am already getting results displayed my concern wasn't about the error in syntax but more of a logical perspective thus i typed in without full syntax.

Comment: This code looks correct, are you doing something else to the computed?

Comment: @BenNelson in my view page i have a data-bind foreach loop to display the filteredUsers but the results only display the list of users i don't want to display and i want it to be the opposite

Comment: Can you show me your data-bind?

Comment: @BenNelson i went ahead and added the data-bind above. thanks

Comment: How are you actually getting the objects in to each observable array? If you're adding them separately it could be because you simply have an item in each array with the name "Tom" and "Jill", but they aren't the same object.

Comment: @michaelDunlap i went ahead and added to my post - if what you are saying is my case how can i go around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to search the Users ObservableArray for a matching item using arrayFirst (returns true if any of the filter function returns true). Since you want users in the full list that are NOT in the normal list, you add a `!` to the arrayFirst. If the attribute to filter on is an observable, make sure to add `()` to the end of the attribute.

```
this._FilteredUsers=ko.computed(function() {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(_self.FullUsers(), function(fuitem) {
        return !ko.utils.arrayFirst(_self.Users(), function(item) {
            return fuitem.Name() === item.Name(); //replace .Name  with the attribute you want to match on
        });
});
```